# File named "auth_actions.dart" won't be highlighted in Intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I created a file named "auth_actions.dart" in a dart project(either angular or not). The file content would have text colour being plain white, without any highlighted.

If I rename it to "auth_action.dart" or "auth_actionss.dart", the highlight will come back.

I did some experiments even from some random projects downloaded from github, all of them had this issue.

Anyone know how to fix it? Does anyone see the same issue using the name "auth_actions.dart"?

Comment: I suspect the color of the file name on Idea might be related to git status... Is that the case?

Comment: It is the text of file content not being highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you accidentally added the file to

```
Preferences > Editor > File Types > Recognized File Types > Text
```

Remove it from `Registered Patterns` to get hightlighting again.

Comment: I did add it to to the registered patterns. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You could accidentally mark it as plain text (the option is in the right-click menu). In this case, the option to mark it back as a Dart file is also in the context menu.